# Membership Expiry System

Tags: php

I need help making this expiry system work.

```
public function isMember(){
    $this->member = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT expire FROM users WHERE username=:username');
    $this->member->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username']);
    if(strtotime(date()) < strtotime($this->member->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And then in the main dashboard it's running the following:

```
if($user->isMember() == false){
  header("Location: purchase.php");
}
```

Comment: so... uh, could you at least describe the problems you're having with it?

Comment: It's not working ?

Comment: @JeremyHenderson how is it not working? any errors or always returning false? Seems like it'd be fine

Comment: @JeremyHenderson have you checked what data has been returned by the query? `echo strtotime($this->member->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` before the ifs and see it isn't something completely unrelated.

Comment: I fixed it; it's fine

Answer (score 1):

You prepared a statement, but you did not execute it.

The `->fetch()` would also have returned an array, so would not have worked in that position.

```
public function isMember(){
    $this->member = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT expire FROM users WHERE username=:username');
    $this->member->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username']);

    $this->member->execute();

    $expire = $this->member->fetchColumn();
    $this->member->closeCursor();

    if(strtotime(date() < strtotime($expire)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: But then you're not closing the strtotime

Comment: Yup, my mistake, see amended answer